# Creating AVD with Hardware Keyboard in Mac OS X 10.8.x

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

I am trying to emulate a Galaxy Nexus device in AVD Manager.  I have checked both `Hardware keyboard present` and `Display a skin with hardware controls`, yet neither of these seem to work when the device is actually started.  Does anyone have any way to enable keyboard input for AVD devices on Mac OS X 10.8.2?

Comment: did you set the boolean to yes for keyboard support?

Comment: If you are doing this only for UI presentation purposes, you can check http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/device-frames.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the config file of your current device at

```
~/.android/avd/<emulator-device-name>.avd/config.ini
```

and see if `hw.keyboard=yes`. If it says `no`, change to `yes`.